# Are set covering problems with nonlinear cost functions NP-Hard?

Tags: computational-complexity, np

Are set covering problems ([set cover problem wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)) with a nonlinear cost function also NP-hard? Is there a general result about this?

To be more specific the cost function I am interested in something like:

\begin{equation}
C(S)=\sum_{s\in S}[ f(|s|)-ln(n_{|s|}(S))]
\end{equation}
 where S is the cover s are the subsets |s| the size of the set s f some positive strictly increasing cost function that only depends on size and $n_{|s|}(S)$ the number of subsets of size |s| in S.